# Fichero externo en Android Stiudio?

Tags: android-studio

Sé que internamente se hace así la escritura

```
 public void escribirFichero(String e){
   String nombre= "fichero.txt";

   FileOutputStream stream;
   try{
   stream= openFileOutput(nombre, MODE_APPEND);
   stream.write(e.getBytes());
   stream.close();
   }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }catch(IOException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Y asi la lectura, pero quisiera saber si se diferencia mucho el método para ficheros externos, llevo mucho lío y me estoy desanimando un poco

```
public void leerFichero(){
       String fichero= "fichero.txt";
       String resulta= "";

       try{
           FileInputStream stream= getApplicationContext().openFileInput(fichero);
           BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

           String tmp= "";

           do{
               tmp= br.readLine();
               if (tmp != null){
                   resulta= resulta+tmp;
               }
           }while (tmp != null);

           t.setText(resulta);
           br.close();
           stream.close();

}catch (FileNotFoundException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       }catch (IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
       }
```

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Si internamente se guardan los ficheros así, externamente es básicamente parecido, necesitas acceder a la ruta externa con el Environment, pero lo demás es practicante parecido:

```
File ruta_sd_global = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File fichero = new File(ruta_sd_global.getAbsolutePath(), "fichero.txt");
    FileOutputStream stream;
    try {
        stream = new FileOutputStream(fichero, false);
        PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter(stream);
        writer.println(texto);
        writer.println(texto);
        writer.close();
        stream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Y para leer es lo mismo ha excepcion de que debes cambiar, la ruta desde la que lees el fichero:

```
File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File fichero = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), "fichero.txt");
```

Comment: Lo he probado y no funciona, igual me falta algo

Answer (score 0):

Vale si no te funciona pueden ser varias cosas la primera, puedes hacer la comprobación de los permisos añadiendo esto:

```
String estado = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (estado.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    sdDisponible = true;
    sdAccesoEscritura = true;
} else if (estado.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
    sdDisponible = true;
    sdAccesoEscritura = false;
} else {
    sdDisponible = false;
    sdAccesoEscritura = false;
}

if(sdDisponible && sdAccesoEscritura)
{
 //AQUI EL CODIGO DE LECTURA
}
```

Si esta primera opción no funciona igual te faltan los permisos en AndroidManifest.xml o dentro del dispositivo darle permisos a la aplicacion para que puede acceder.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Poner multiples respuestas esta mal visto. si tenes que modificar algo, modifica tu respuesta original.